# Bowtie2 is expecting a Documents/Python folder. why?

Tags: python, bowtie

I have recently downloaded Bowtie2-2.3.4 via the precompiled binaries, and added the file location to my path.  I have also installed strawberry perl, and added that location to my path as well.
When I try to determine whether bowtie2 is correctly installed by typing `bowtie2`, `bowtie2 -- version`, `bowtie1 - inspect`, get the message: "Can't open perl script "C:\Users\lberd\Documents\Python": No such file or directory".  If I create an empty directory called Python in my documents folder, it give me "Can't open perl script "C:\Users\lberd\Documents\Python": Permission denied".
I have python 3.9.5 installed, and the location is in my path as well.

What is bowtie2 looking for in the python folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: the bowtie binaries were saved in a folder called "python scripts"  bowtie did not know how to handle the space in the folder name, which is why it stopped at "python".